# Understanding how to size figures for publication-ready graphics using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think the key word in my title (which I know isn't quite framed as a question, apologies) is 'understanding.' It would be immensely helpful if someone could point me to a good resource for understanding how the sizing of figures produced with ggplot2 actually works.

Typically, when I go to export images from R for use in scientific journal publications, I end up playing around with the margins in par(), guessing at appropriate height and width, and messing around with the size of my axis labels and titles etc. in each plot until everything fits together. But I never actually know what I'm doing, and this takes a long time and isn't very efficient!

Right now, specifically, I would like to create and export one large figure which is made up of several smaller scatterplots. However, when I search online for guidance with multipanel plots in ggplot2, I only seem to find help using facet_wrap and face_grid. I don't think this is appropriate for my purposes, though, because I do not have discrete variables for grouping.

Any advice on this topic or any resources one might recommend would be very much appreciated.

Comment: look at `patchwork` for assembling manny ggplots into one figure

Comment: Another pretty good choice is the `cowplot` - it lets you glue several `ggplot2` objects into a single figure.

Comment: Check out https://minimaxir.com/2017/08/ggplot2-web/

Comment: As for messing around with the size of the plot, axis labels, etc..., I'm not sure if there's any simple solution. Journals will typically give you a preferred figure dimensions (i.e. "x by y cm"), and you can then use `ggsave()` with those dimension to save it. However, you will most likely still have to adjust size of the axis font, geoms, etc... so that the figure is actually legible in those dimensions. I think that unfortunately that's just par for the course of making good figures.